# jquery sortable in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to send task id using ajax whenever a user sorts table rows based on their preference. but it doesn't seem like the data captured in ajax is sent to the controller. i have debugged the code andthe data is captured in jQuery, but ajax doesn't send it. what may the problem be? here's my code. 
my task index

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
  @section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#sortable").sortable({
            update: function (event, ui) {
                var itemIds = ""; 
  $("#sortable").find(".taskSingleInline").each(function () 
     {
                     var itemId = $(this).attr("data-taskid");
                     itemIds = itemIds + itemId + ",";
                 });
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateItem", "TaskBoard")',
                data: { itemIds: itemIds },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
}
 <style>
     #sortable tr:hover {
         background-color: cadetblue;
         color: beige;
     }
 </style>


 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TaskBoard", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="sortable" style="cursor:pointer;">
                @foreach (var i in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@i.Id</td>
                        <td class="taskSingleInline" id="task@(i.Id)" data-taskid="@(i.Id)">@i.Name</td>
                        <td>@i.RowNo</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button type="submit"> submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

and here is my controller

```
    public ActionResult UpdateItem(string itemIds)
    {
        int count = 1;         
        List<int> itemIdList = new List<int>();
        itemIdList = itemIds.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToList();
        foreach( var i in itemIdList)
        {
            try
            {
                First f = TE.Firsts.Where(x => x.Id == i).FirstOrDefault();                  
                f.RowNo = count;
                TE.Firsts.AddOrUpdate(f);
                TE.SaveChanges();
            } catch(Exception)
            {
                continue;
            }
            count++;

        }
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

where TF is my Db context
my models "first"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwIAP.png)

and i have rendered there in my shared _layout

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: is the value of your itemIds variable in your controller actually null or are you just saying that the function doesn't work?

Comment: i don't think my jquery is working or my controller function. the itemids is not null if that's what you are asking.

Comment: i just removed my try-catch block and got this exception System.InvalidOperationException
The property 'RowNo' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Comment: The problem is in your controller/model not jquery. Ensure that you have the correct primary key setup in your Firsts table.

Comment: thank you..yes the problem was with my firsts table. i fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with my firsts table. i removed the try-catch block to see the exception and apparently all the fields in my firsts table were set as primary keys? i don't recall doing that, i have no idea how it happened, so i removed the identity from all the fields except for the id and it worked just fine, i hope this was somehow helpful.